# Fieldset with display: table-column disappears entirely in IE8 & IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, fieldset

I just spent some trying to figure out why some form content vanished entirely in IE8 & IE9. After some investigation, it looks like it's the fault of having fieldset set to display:table-column. If I set fieldset to display:table or display:block then everything shows up fine, again.

When testing this html on my IE8 & IE9 virtual machines, I can see only the heading "Not inside a fieldset". If I remove the fieldset styling, I can see both.

Does anyone know why this happens?

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
fieldset
{
display: table-column; 
vertical-align: top
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form>
    <fieldset>
    <div class="row">
        <h6>Inside a fieldset</h6>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
<form>

<h6>Not inside a fieldset</h6>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `display: table-column` means it acts like the `<col>` tag in HTML. The `<col>` tag is an invisible element which is used to specify properties of the column like styles etc. It is not the same as `<td>` (which is `display: table-cell`).

You should use `table-cell` instead.

[**W3C Spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html)

[**Source - Random832's answer in this SO Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617418/how-is-a-css-display-table-column-supposed-to-work)

**EDIT:** `table-column` still gets displayed in IE 7, FireFox 24, Chrome and Opera 15. It doesn't work in IE 8, 9 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

All elements are default positioned to vertically top. You need not to write any extra code. I believe below code should suffice:

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
fieldset
{
height: 50px;  /*************** Not Required, Just to show what I mean by my sentence     mentioned above :) ****************/
}
h6,div {
margin: 0; padding:0;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<fieldset>
<div class="row">
    <h6>Inside a fieldset</h6>
</div>
</fieldset>
<form>

<h6>Not inside a fieldset</h6>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One more thing; For any website reset css is very much necessary. Hope this helps.