# IE 11 is not displaying contact form 7 forms in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins

I'm a website designer completely lost on *why* my contact form 7 forms are not displaying at all in wordpress:

https://ahaproperties.com/wp/summerhill-woods-apartments/summerhill-woods-contact-us/

I've tried forcing IE 7 compatibility mode (which I learned from another post) by placing this in the head:  ''

But then IE gave me this error:  *Unable to get property 'prototype' of undefined or null reference.*

I can see the form in the source code...but what is the solution to make it display in the browser?  Everything looks fine in all other browsers.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just checked your site using IE11 (on Windows 10) and I can see a Contact form there.

Comment: I think you might have been looking at a wordpress default theme - both the client and myself are still seeing just a blank after clearing cache and history :(    Does the page you see look like this?  https://ahaproperties.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Capture.jpg

Comment: It does appear to be an issue, as IE 11 shots are 2nd, 3rd and last here:  https://ahaproperties.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/browser_shots.jpg

Comment: In my first post, I used the wrong 'tick' - sorry about that - This is what I tried to put in header.php.  `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />`  Sorry about that.   It didn't work unfortunately - I think I need a super hero ;)

Comment: Check my answer below, I tested it on IE 11 and it fixed the issue for me :)

Answer (score 0):

In the stylesheet named `g1-screen.css`, line 378, you have this:

```
/* ----->>> FORMS <<<--------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
fieldset { display: table-column; min-width: inherit; }
```

Internet Explorer 11 doesn't support `display: table-column` (nor do IE 10, IE 9 or IE 8 according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479871/fieldset-with-display-table-column-disappears-entirely-in-ie8-ie9)).

Change that to:

```
/* ----->>> FORMS <<<--------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
fieldset { display: table-cell; min-width: inherit; }
```

or:

```
/* ----->>> FORMS <<<--------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
fieldset { display: block; min-width: inherit; }
```

and it'll work.

Alternatively, you can also add the following CSS snippet to your theme's stylesheet to change only how CF7's fieldsets are displayed:

```
.wpcf7-form fieldset {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: OMG I owe you a fruit basket if this works.  Checking now!

Comment: Bless you - I have success :)   I went for the last solution to avoid theme update overwrites.  I don't suppose you have a magic snippet to make the checkboxes/radio buttons sit on the baseline, do you?  They are hanging too high for some reason.

Comment: I'm restarting my laptop now (damn Windows updates...) so I can't have a look at the moment. And you should open a new question for that, too :P Please accept this answer and I'll go have a look at the new one as soon as I can.

Comment: Pls Disregard my checkbox question as I found the proper css for this on another post - Thanks so much again.  I will inform the theme developer of your finding.

Answer (score 0):

The below worked immediately. I put this under "Customize" and "Additional CSS" in Wordpress:

...you can also add the following CSS snippet to your theme's stylesheet to change only how CF7's fieldsets are displayed:

```
.wpcf7-form fieldset {
display: table-cell;
}
```