# html form to automatically resize itself depending on the output inside of it via css3

Tags: html, forms, css, resize

How can I set up a form to automatically resize itself with css3?

The form should automatically resize itself depending on the largest text output in the form, anyone got an idea how to do it? Static sizes with pixel width and height aren't friendly... I'm using a table btw

Code(too low reputation to post more than 2 links): jsfiddle.net/HfyLL/

Comment: don't use a table? [What is wrong with using tables in responsive utilities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406251/what-is-wrong-with-using-tables-in-responsive-utilities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean a `css` like this?

```
.acc-form {
    width: 350px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index:5;

    background: #f3f3f3;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;

    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border:solid;}
table td{border:solid;}
.dark{background-color:#000000;width:100px;}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RmQPG/)