# Correct way to use display : table-column

Tags: css, html

I was watching the different option for the CSS property "display", and was trying the `display : table-...`, everything is working fine but I have some trouble with `display : table-column` and `display : table-column-group` wich doesn't show anything as the other option let my div to be shown.
I don't really get how thing are working with the table display.

Here is my code

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="zi-1 zone-info">TEXT1</div>
    <div class="zi-2 zone-info">TEXT2</div>
</div>

.wrapper { display: table }

.zone-info {
    display: table-column-group;
}

.zi-1 {
    background-color:yellow;
}

.zi-2 {
    background-color:magenta;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nc6L227z/4/)

**Question**

What is the proper way of using the `table-column` option

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617418/how-is-a-css-display-table-column-supposed-to-work

Comment: Before table-column you must use table-row