# Convert table to div with CSS without tbody

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mysql

I want to convert a table to div tables, but when I created the table in Dreamweaver it just added the `<tbody>` tag. Does I need it when converting the table to div-table ?

Here is the code of the table

```
<table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see I want a table using divs with

```
width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
```

What is the correct way to do that? And is neccesary to set another div for the `<tbody>` tag ?

Comment: Just curious as to why you would like to have it that way? For answer, you could use the css property 'display: table'

Comment: here a table of 4 cells on top of each others can be turned into any 4 block level tags. tbody is part of the regular table structure, thead and tfooter then can be used. If not in the HTML code, browser will still emulate it.

Comment: My idea is to convert my old tablet design to div design

Comment: Please stop using DreamWeaver :(

Comment: @Sagar - I will answer that: When you wish your tables to be responsive and render in a different manner on mobile devices (narrow viewpoert), simulating a table using CSS instead of actual *table* tags allows a degree of freedom you otherwise won't have.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/29229523/104380

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td"></div>
    <div class="td"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td"></div>
    <div class="td"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table .tr {
  display: table-row;
}
.table .td {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Hope this works for you. :)

Comment: So the tbody is not needed to add an extra div for it?

Comment: No,  that HTML i wrote is all you need: :)