# grid-area not working in neocities, how do I fix this?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with the grid layout system in css, while I am following the official guide from Mozilla, even copying and pasting their code still gives me an error.

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; /*columns defined as a fraction of the grid*/
  grid-template-rows: auto; /*rows defined relative to the amount of areas*/
  grid-template-areas: 
  "header header header"
  "main main sidebar" 
  "footer footer footer";
}
.header {
  grid-area: header;

}
```

despite any attempts to troubleshoot the code so far, the grid-area line gives me `unknown property 'grid-area'`

neocities doesn't have any unique documentation. Is this simply an editor quirk? And is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

If by "*editor quirk*" you mean "*is this a false positive because the editor doesn't have synatx rules for CSS Grid*", then yes, it appears to be an editor problem. Neocities uses Ace Editor, which doesn't support CSS Grid yet (see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/4025), from what I can tell.

Assuming it lets you save your changes, I would ignore those errors - as long as the browser supports [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid#browser_compatibility), it will work anyway. The CSS Grid spec is still in active development, though, so you might want to consider fallback rules.

As for alternatives, you might be able to approximate a grid layout with flexbox (which has fairly good support at this point). You may also find this question and answer useful, [How (and why) to use display: table-cell (CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229523/how-and-why-to-use-display-table-cell-css), if styling your content as though it were table content is acceptable.

Comment: Neocities uses Ace Editor? Good to know, I will attempt to use flexbox as well and see if it's a better fit.

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes, from looking at the source code, Neocities uses Ace Editor. I'm not really all that familiar with Neocities (I knew about it, but have never had a reason to use it), so take that with a healthy pinch of salt. If you don't need an in-browser editor, you can probably use something like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), [Brackets](http://brackets.io/), or [Atom](https://atom.io/) (or whatever else floats your boat).