# How to use css to break text line

Tags: html, css

I have some text which I want to divide into two. As I understand, this can be done using css display -(see W3 School) The problem is that when I try to use `display: table-column` or `display: table-column-group` for example, which should put my text in a column and divide, (W3 school) the text disappears from the page. As soon as I use `display: inherit;` though, for exanple, (all the text on one line) it reappears.

```
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt $awpcpdisplayaditems $isfeaturedclass" data-breakpoints-class-prefix="awpcp-listing-excerpt" data-breakpoints='{"tiny": [0,328], "small": [328,600], "medium": [600,999999]}'>
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail">
    $awpcp_image_name_srccode
</div>
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-inner" style="w">
    <h4 class="awpcp-listing-title">$title_link</h4>
    <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-content">$excerpt</div>
</div>
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra">

    $awpcp_city_display
    $awpcp_state_display
    $awpcp_display_adviews
    $awpcp_display_price
    $awpcpextrafields
```

Css:

```
.awpcp-listing-title {display: table-column !important;}
```

Comment: [That's not what `display: table-column` is for.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617418/how-is-a-css-display-table-column-supposed-to-work) What does "put my text in a column and divide" mean? Can you make a mockup of what you're expecting?

Comment: Not reallyz don't know how to do that. But here is page: https://adsler.co.uk/browse-adsler/see how text expands outside the box... Mobile view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while but this seems to have worked.

```
.awpcp-listing-title {
background-color: 
unset;position: unset; padding: 
unset; font-size: 12px; margin- 
left:-80px; margin-right: 120px;
```

The combination of negative `margin-left` to position the text, and `margin-right` which seems to have squeezed it into 3 lines.