# Div element with display table-column is not visible

Tags: html, css, html-table, display

```css
.table             { display: table;        }
.table > div       { display: table-column; }
.table > div > div { display: table-cell;   }
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Just</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>World!</div>
    <div>Testing</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The table is not visible here. But when I change `table-column` to `table-row`, it suddenly becomes visible:

```css
.table             { display: table;        }
.table > div       { display: table-row;    }
.table > div > div { display: table-cell;   }
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Just</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>World!</div>
    <div>Testing</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to make the first snippet work without using the `<table>` element? I am on Chrome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is a CSS "display: table-column" supposed to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617418/how-is-a-css-display-table-column-supposed-to-work)

Comment: A `table-col` element behaves like the `<col>` element, which is itself not-visible, and used to define common CSS for elements within that 'column'. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display-internal