# CSS - Align numbers above checkboxes?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a feedback system, were there are questions with 5 check boxes for "Unwilling", "Not Ready", "Ready", "Completely Ready" etc...

Each check box is numbered from 1 to 5 above the check boxes. Since the client needs to add different labels for the check boxes, their lengths will be different so this needs to change with CSS rather than be fixed.

Here was a photoshop mock-up from our designer of what I am suppose to create in CSS.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8XyG.jpg

How could I align the numbers above the check box like this?

I already have the outside box, and the start of the number part:

**CSS:**

```
.questionBlock {
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    width: 700px;
    min-height: 40px;
    background-color: rgb(246,246,246);
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-image: url('../images/bar.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    padding: 4px 0 0 10px;
}
.questionBlockExpand {
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    width: 700px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(246,246,246);
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
    .innerQuestionBlock {
        postion:relative;
        width:650px;
        background-color:rgb(204,204,204);  
        padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="questionBlock">At the end of the session ask the Feedback Recipient the following question:
    <div class="arrow" id="arrowsection1" onclick="toggle_visibility('section1');"></div>
    <div class="questionBlockExpand" id="section1" style="display:none;">
        <div class="innerQuestionBlock"><span class="red">1 2 3 4 5</span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show your HTML too???

Comment: Am I correct in thing I need to add a DIV for each checkbox? then overlay the text on top of them?

Comment: @Mayank Hello again... HTML is added to the post now.

Comment: The simpliest way to do it would be to use a `table`. The only thing you got to do is to style differently the three rows. The second one should have `colspan="5"`, in order to display the "How ready do you feel to take action" text correctly.

Comment: would the question be very long sometimes ? I would suggest you to use labels after or before the checkboxes anyway, using for="id", it boosts the usability as when you click on the label it's triggering the checkbox itself as well this way

Comment: @aleation My intention was to do this eventually with labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use percentage instead of px values.
So let's say you have two lists (`<ul>`): one with the numbers and the other with the answers.

Both `<ul>` has `width:100%` so they will pick up the width of the parent element.
In those lists each item has a `width:20%` (100% / 5 = 20%)

That will make it pretty dynamic, without using nasty tables.

Here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tQD6w/) too.

*PS: bare in mind if you'd like to add padding to the items it has to be in percentage as well and the amount will reduce the width*

Comment: Beautiful. I was about to post my JSfiddle but you beat me to it :P

Comment: what if one checkbox text have more text and can't fit a 20% of width where at same time another checkbox may require only 5% of width. look at given mockup a feel spacing between 1,2,3,4..

Comment: @Absar: and how is your answer addressing that? have you checked it in a fiddle using this scenario? Moreover, tables are for tabular data not for layouts.

Comment: @Absar: see: http://jsfiddle.net/F3LsL/5/ too much text will break it! anyway, thanks for the effort.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Everything has been so helpful. I will likely use this method.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at mock-up i would use a table

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td>11</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>5</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td colspan="5">Some other content comes here<td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox">Lorem</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox">Ipsum</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox">Dolor</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox">Lorem</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox">Amit</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, Using a table suddenly makes perfect sense!

Comment: i would strongly recommend against it...`table` is outdated in most places and you have options like `display:table` nowdays!!

Comment: @Mayank Is there an alternative?

Comment: @Mayank  yet `<table>` is fine in this scenario. we're not using it for a full page layout.

Comment: @Absar I don't think so. It's definitely not a table just a layout that might seen "table-ish" so if it can be done it should be done without tables.

Comment: @Absar : its not about the layout mate.....its about the layout designed with most up-to-date standards...

Comment: @Mayank So many different fiddles and methods! Not sure whether to use CSS or Table?!

Comment: @Joey : its simple.....avoid table...read this thread => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867476/why-should-i-use-displaytable-instead-of-table

Answer (score 1):

Would suggest you to use DIVs or ULs with `display:table`. Primary reason being, the info that you want to show is not tabular data semantically. It has to do more with layout.

See this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/F3LsL/1/**

Idea is to use floated divs within a div for the counter numbers on the top with a pre-defined width. Then use either a list or another div to display your checkboxes with the same width.

For example:

```
div.counters > div {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest  [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nN6Zt/15/)

simple idea is to draw `table` display and assign same style to both `number` and `checkbox` as below

**css**

```
.chkbx {
    width:100%;
}
.ratings {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #F00;
}
.ratings > span {
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:20%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="chkbx">
    <div class="ratings"> 
        <span class="bx">1</span>
        <span class="bx">2</span>
        <span class="bx">3</span>
        <span class="bx">4</span>
        <span class="bx">5</span>

    </div>

    <div class="ftext"> Some full text here </div>

     <div class="ratings"> 
         <span class="bx">Lorem<input type="checkbox" /></span>
         <span class="bx">Lorem <input type="checkbox" /></span>
         <span class="bx">Lorem <input type="checkbox" /></span>
         <span class="bx">Lorem <input type="checkbox" /></span>
         <span class="bx">Lorem <input type="checkbox" /></span>

    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Just realised it is supposed to be a ratio button, not check box! oops.

Comment: Are you using Dreamweaver?

Comment: @Joey : nope...i working on jsfiddle directly, dont have any editor except notepad ryt nw!! :) ~~~~~~~  and change checkbox to radio, that should not a be problem :)